# plugman not recognising project

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I've been following Scandit's [guide](https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin#changelog) to setting up a project in phonegap to make use of their library.

So the list of commands I call are:

```
cordova create . 
cordova platform add ios 
plugman install --platform ios --project . --plugin <path to unzipped ScanditSDK Plugin for iOS>
```

but on the last command, it throws the error:

```
does not appear to be an xcode project (no xcode project file)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I also ran `cordova build ios` in case it needed some initiation, but that didn't do it. Maybe it's because I haven't made any custom additions to the bare structure yet?

This is all using phonegap 3.0

Answer (score 10):

if you are running plugman from the same directory where you called

> cordova platform add ios

you will need to add the path to the directory where the above command created the ios project e.g.

> plugman --platform ios --project platforms/ios --plugin path-to-scanditsdk

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, and now I get:


`Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Uh oh!
cannot find {appdir}/platforms/ios/cordova/plugins/com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin/src/ios/scanditsdk-community-ios_3.0.4/ScanditSDK/libscanditsdk-iphone-3.0.4.a" ios <source-file>`

And this is from the latest version of https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin

Comment: By me it worked good. I've used this plugin and cordova 3.0.0 https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner